# Rango de fechas. ¿Cómo crear una lista que contenga como items todos los dias entre dos fechas dadas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Tengo dos fechas una inicial y una final (estas fechas son proporcionadas por el usuario). Quiero crear en Python 3 una lista que contenga las fechas en formato *YYYY-MM-DD* a partir de las fechas que fueron ingresadas.

Ejemplo:

```
fecha_inicial = 2017-10-01
fecha_final = 2017-10-05

lista_fechas = ['2017-10-01', '2017-10-02', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-04', '2017-10-05']
```

El las fechas serían objetos `datetime.`

Intenté con este código, pero no logro construir la lista por compresión:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

inicio = datetime(2017,10,1)
fin   = datetime(2017,10,5)

print(inicio)
print(fin)


diferencia = fin - inicio

print (diferencia)

lista_fecha = [inicio]
lista_fecha = [fecha for fecha in (inicio, fin)]
print(lista_fecha)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Alejandro. ¿Has intentado algo?¿En que formato tienes las fechas?¿Son cadenas (en que formato: "dd/mm/aaaa", etc) u objetos `datetime`?¿Como quieres la lista de salida, con cadenas (en este caso con qué formato) o `datetime`? Agrega algo más de información, puedes mirarte [tour] y [ask] para conocer un poco mejor el sitio y como hacer preguntas con más posibilidades de obtener buenas respuestas. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola. Gracias por la respuesta, las fechas  que tengo son objetos datetime, la lista de salida la quiero por en intervalos de un día. es decir si la fecha inicial es 2017-10-01 y la fecha final es 2017-10-05, entonces la lista de salida deberá ser lista_salida = ['2017-10-01', '2017-10-02', '2017-10-03', 2017-10-04, '2017-10-05']. como se puede apreciar el formato es YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Alejandro la solución pasa por usar `datetime.timedelta`, si el usuario ingresa las fechas con un input usamos `datetime.strptime` para pasarlas a `datetime`, luego usando un `for` + `range` (listas por compresión sería lo mejor) y `datetime.timedelta` creamos la lista con el intervalo entre fechas deseado (1 dia). Si la lista la quieres con cadenas usa `datetime.strftime` para pasar de `datetime` a `str` con el formato que quieras ("%y-%m-%d" para YYYY-MM-DD). Intenta algo y añádelo a la pregunta si no terminas de dar con la clave para que la pregunta pueda ser reabierta. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, creo que lo que me comentas es exactamente lo que necesito, ya traté de hacer la lista a través de una comprehension list, sin embargo no logro el resultado esperado, si me pudieras ayudar con el código que lo agradeceré mucho sinceramente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como ya te comenté la clave está en usar `datetime.timedelta` junto a `range`:

```
inicio = datetime(2017,10,1)
fin    = datetime(2017,10,5)

lista_fechas = [inicio + timedelta(days=d) for d in range((fin - inicio).days + 1)] 
print(lista_fechas)
```

**Salida:**

```
[datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 3, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 4, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 5, 0, 0)]
```

**Explicación:**

- El primer paso es obtener el tiempo que hay en el periodo comprendido entre ambas fechas. Para ello restamos las dos fechas tal y como ya haces tú. Como necesitamos el número de días, ya que este es el paso o intervalo entre las fechas que quieres usamos el atributo `.days` que retorna un entero con el número de días en ese periodo. Como quieres incluir el día final y `range` no retorna el valor final (argumento `stop`), necesitamos sumar 1.
- Usamos `timedelta` que nos permite ir sumando el numero de días retornado por `range`  a la fecha inicial.

---

Si quieres obtener las fechas en forma de cadenas (`str`) con formato "YYYY-MM-DD", en vez de objetos `datetime.datetime`, necesitamos usar el método `strftime` que retorna la fecha del objeto `datetime.datetime`  como una cadena (`str`) de acuerdo al formato proporcionado en el argumento pasado.

```
lista_fechas = [(inicio + timedelta(days=d)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                    for d in range((fin - inicio).days + 1)] 
print(lista_fechas)
```

**Salida:**

```
['2017-10-01', '2017-10-02', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-04', '2017-10-05']
```

---

Documentación oficial relevante:

- Builting [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range).
- [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).
- [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).
- [Códigos de formato](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) para `strftime` y `strptime`.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación y por el código. En verdad lo aprecio

Comment: Si con gusto lo hago