# ¿Cómo devolver lista con segundos intermedios en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como puedo devolver una lista de todos los segundos intermedios Por ejemplo para “10:10:10” y “15:15:15” devolver: ["10:10:10", "10:10:11", ... "15:15:14", "15:15:15"]*

tengo que usar el modulo datatime y hacer un contador?

busque en la documentación de python y no puedo encontrar el resultado deseado que me pueden recomendar?

Comment: Puedes crear tu propio algoritmo teniendo en cuenta el rango de los segundos y minutos (0-59) y horas (0-23). si quieres usar la biblioteca estándar `datetime.time` no soporta `timedelta` , tendrías que usar `datetime.datetime`  haciendo algo similar [Rango de fechas. ¿Cómo crear una lista que contenga como items todos los dias entre dos fechas dadas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/110479/15089) pero con un incremento de segundos y no de dias. Dada la simplicidad del algoritmo en este caso yo optaría por implementarlo, se puede hacer con condicionales o con ayuda del operador módulo `%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que hacer un parsing de fechas, te dejo un ejemplo comentado con dos horas de diferencia

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def lapsus( h1, h2 ):
    #Declaramos la list
    sec = []
    #Obtenemos un valor absoluto en segundos según la resta de estos horarios
    hh3 = abs( abs( h1 - h2 ).seconds )

    #Ciclamos hh3 para agregar cada segundo a la list
    for x in range(hh3):
        #Con time delta agregamos segundos
        sec.append( (h1 + timedelta( seconds = x ) ).strftime( "%H:%M:%S" ) )

    return sec
#Obtenemos las horas que vamos a pasar
hora1 = datetime.now()
hora2 = datetime.now() + timedelta( hours = 2 )

print( lapsus(hora1, hora2) )
```